# How do i get the following code to scrape all the menu items listed in this web page?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

### I want to get all the menu items listed on the web page but my code only returns only 14 items.

```
     import pandas as pd
     from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
     import requests
     import re
     data=[]
     res=requests.get("https://www.beyondmenu.com/39214/san-diego/minh-ky-chinese-restaurant-san-diego-92115.aspx")
     soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
     listings=soup.findAll(class_='items_wrapper')
     for listing in listings:
        listing_title=listing.find('h4')
        full_dict={'title':listing_title}
        data.append(full_dict)


 df=pd.DataFrame(data)
 print(df)
```

### How do i fix this code so that i  can get all menu items  from the first item i.e. Rice Stick & Pancit Noodles Soup to the last menu item Sea food with bean curd pot

Comment: hi there good evening dear dwebb: i run this on my fairly new PyCharm in the office - which may lack some final customization i get back  ` File "C:/Users/Kasper/.PyCharmEdu2019.2/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 2
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Process finished with exit code 1`

hmm - iguess that there are some issues on my customization - i a m pretty sure that your results were even better. I have todo some investigations here on my machine - andi  will try it at home on a linux box with Atom . see you

Comment: Just fix the indentation error. May be i made a mistake when i copied the code, then tell me what you get.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is?

Comment: I need to scrape all the menu items from the web page. But my code only returns 14 items.

Comment: hi there - many thanks - now it works for me too!! keep up the great work dwebb!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.beyondmenu.com/39214/san-diego/minh-ky-chinese-restaurant-san-diego-92115.aspx")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

menu = [item.text for item in soup.findAll("td", style="width: 80%")]

print(menu)
```